# Spring Boot doesn't see security dependencies

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, implements

I'am trying to implements UserDetails by SecurityCore.

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String email;
    private String password;

}
```

After hover on UserDetails , I see `Cannot resolve symbol 'UserDetails'`

This is my dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.BooksShop-Backend</groupId>
    <artifactId>REST-API</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>REST-API</name>
    <description>BooksShop-Backend-REST API</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Why am I unable to see something similar to this? My terminal is functioning correctly, and all dependencies have been installed correctly. I removed some dependencies due to posting limitations, but I kept the security dependency.

[image]

Comment: remove `spring-security-core` and `spring-security-web` because `spring-boot-starter-security` from your `pom.xml` already contain these dependency

Comment: Deleted and still isn't working.

Comment: can you share the project on github and i will check ?

Comment: https://github.com/DaroGawlik/Java-BooksShop-Backend and please check out "class SecurityConfiguration" I have tried to add SecurityFilterChain() and received "Cannot resolve symbol 'SecurityFilterChain'".

Comment: ok, i`m going to post the answer as soon as i will have an result

Comment: just have a look here [securing-web](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) and also i don`t see your user class that implements UserDetails

Comment: I performed a hard reset of my commits, and now everything is working correctly.